# Why does my html work when i say it but it doesn't work on jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-api, jsfiddle

I've written a perfectly well-formed html with javascripts to call google APIs, when i save it on my machine in .html, it works fine. But when i copy and pasted it onto jsfiddle, the synthesizer section wont work. http://jsfiddle.net/LNpYB/33/

Any idea why?

Comment: Don't know.  If you tested it and it works in a real browser, why are you worried about jsfiddle?

Comment: because i dont have a hosting domain, so when i present my little script, i have to use jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me maybe one time in 20.

Type the url into a browser and it will work, open it from a link and an http inspector shows that Google returns a 404 for the same url.

They are only allowing TTS use via requests that don't contain a referrer (local pages do not).

Comment: going direct to the link works, but somehow i might need to show my demo on my local machine. i dont have a hosted domain. http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=de&q=ich+bin+schwanger+.+das+ist+nicht+fett+.+das+ist+baby+.+und+du+bis+doch+sein+vater+

Comment: @2er0 Run a local server instance.

Answer (score 1):

See your browser javascript console.

Chrome: F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I

[image]

Comment: I actually _do not_ see those errors when I test in Chrome. I get no console output.

Comment: i guess you need to upgrade then

Comment: Um, no. v.21.0 is up to date.

Comment: well, thats my chrome up there. *shrug*

Comment: Firefox reports a 404 on the media resource: `Warning: HTTP load failed with status 404. Load of media resource http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=talk%20please failed.`  No JS error though.

Comment: it wont work on firefox because it's calling a chrome api. even the hardcopy of html on my machine dont work with firefox.

i have checked my chrome console, i dont have that javascript attempt warning